# How to prevent same Images from repeating itself?

Tags: android

I'm currently working on a country flag quiz. The coding is set so that the player will recieve a new random flag each time and where the player has to guess by pressing 1 of 4 answerButtons. Whether the player guesses right or wrong next flag should load and same country flag shouldn't repeat itself until all flags have been displayed or if the player has lost all their lives (= 5 lives) and the game restarts (this part isn't programmed yet). However, that's not the case. Now and then, same flag re-appears for some strange reasons, can't figure out how to completely prevent this.

**PROBLEM:** 
How do I go about to prevent same flag from re-appearing, until all flags have been displayed?

.

**JAVA-file:**

```
public class EasyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String Folder = "Easy";
    private ImageView flagImageView;
    private List<String> countries;
    private List<Button> suggestionsBtns;
    private int currentCountryIndex;
    private final static Random random = new Random ();
    TextView currentScoreTextView;
    TextView currentLivesTextView;
    TextView answerTextViewEasy;
    Animation shakeAnimation;

    int correctAnswer = 0;
    int currentScore = 1;
    int currentLives = 5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_easy);

        answerTextViewEasy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextViewEasy);
        currentScoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentScoreEasy);
        currentLivesTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentLivesEasy);

        loadCountries ();
        initUi ();

        try {
            randomize ();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }//onCreate ends here


    private void randomize () throws Exception {
        currentCountryIndex = random.nextInt (countries.size ());

        InputStream is = getAssets ().open (Folder + File.separator + countries.get (currentCountryIndex));
        flagImageView.setImageBitmap (BitmapFactory.decodeStream (is));
        is.close ();

        int randomCountry1 = getRandomIndex (countries.size (), currentCountryIndex);
        int randomCountry2 = getRandomIndex (countries.size (), currentCountryIndex, randomCountry1);
        int randomCountry3 = getRandomIndex (countries.size (), currentCountryIndex, randomCountry1, randomCountry2);

        int randomCorrectCountryPos = getRandomIndex (4);
        int randomCountry1Pos     = getRandomIndex (4, randomCorrectCountryPos);
        int randomCountry2Pos     = getRandomIndex (4, randomCorrectCountryPos, randomCountry1Pos);
        int randomCountry3Pos     = getRandomIndex (4, randomCorrectCountryPos, randomCountry1Pos, randomCountry2Pos);

        suggestionsBtns.get (randomCorrectCountryPos).setText (countries.get (currentCountryIndex).split (".png")[0]);
        suggestionsBtns.get (randomCountry1Pos).setText (countries.get (randomCountry1).split (".png")[0]);
        suggestionsBtns.get (randomCountry2Pos).setText (countries.get (randomCountry2).split (".png")[0]);
        suggestionsBtns.get (randomCountry3Pos).setText (countries.get (randomCountry3).split (".png")[0]);

    }//randomisze ends here


    private int getRandomIndex (int size, Integer... excludes) {
        List<Integer> excludeList = Arrays.asList (excludes);
        int number;
        do {
            number = random.nextInt (size);
        } while (excludeList.contains (number));

        return number;

    }//getRandomIndex ends here


    private void loadCountries () {
        countries = new ArrayList<> ();
        try {
            String [] list = getAssets().list (Folder);
            countries = Arrays.asList (list);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

    }//loadCountries ends here


    private void checkCorrectness (String chosenCountry) {
        if (chosenCountry.equals (countries.get (currentCountryIndex).split (".png")[0])) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= correctAnswer; i++) {
                currentScore = currentScore + i;
            }//for-loop ends here
            correctAnswer++;
            currentScore++;
            String score = Integer.toString(currentScore);
            currentScoreTextView.setText(score);
            String answerText = chosenCountry;
            answerTextViewEasy.setText(answerText + "!");
            answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.correct_answer));
        }else{
            currentLives--;
            String lives = Integer.toString(currentLives);
            currentLivesTextView.setText(lives);
            answerTextViewEasy.setText("Incorrect!");
            answerTextViewEasy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.incorrect_answer));
            shakeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.incorrect_shake);
            shakeAnimation.setRepeatCount(3);
            flagImageView.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);
        }//else ends here
            try {
                randomize ();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }//try-loop ends here
    }//checkCorrectness ends here


    private void initUi () {
        flagImageView = (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.flagImageViewEasy);

        suggestionsBtns = new ArrayList<>();
        suggestionsBtns.add ((Button)findViewById (R.id.answerButton1Easy));
        suggestionsBtns.add ((Button)findViewById (R.id.answerButton3Easy));
        suggestionsBtns.add ((Button)findViewById (R.id.answerButton2Easy));
        suggestionsBtns.add ((Button)findViewById (R.id.answerButton4Easy));

        for (final Button btn : suggestionsBtns) {
            btn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {

                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) {
                    checkCorrectness (btn.getText ().toString ());
                }//onClick ends here
            });
        }//for-loop ends here
    }//initUi ends here

}//EasyActivity ends here
```

**XML-file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/quizLinearLayoutEasy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.android.kingofflags.EasyActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentScoreText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:text="@string/current_score"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentScoreEasy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/current_score_0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="205dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lives"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/lives"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentLivesEasy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lives_5"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flagImageViewEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guessCountryTextViewEasy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/guess_country"
        android:textColor="#4c4c4c"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1LinearLayoutEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2LinearLayoutEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row3LinearLayoutEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerButton1Easy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerButton2Easy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row4LinearLayoutEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerButton3Easy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerButton4Easy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerTextViewEasy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `The coding is set so that the player will recieve a new random flag each time`. Nothing learned. 'will receive a new random image from assets each time'.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an integer list that is empty at the beginning. Upon displaying a flag, save its position to this list, and before displaying the flag, check inside this list. If the flag position is inside the list, it is already displayed, pick another one. If list size = flag list size, then you've displayed all the flags.

Comment: Appreciate your respons. I'm new to Android, so if you have any coding suggestion, I would highly appreciate the help. I got help setting this code up (the part that takes care of the random flag displaying and the list they are included in to prevent the repeat of the flags).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is to sort the list of countries randomly after loading them and then just work your way through the list.

Comment: It's a bit difficult, since I got help with setting this code up to get the random flags to work. I'm not sure how to go about fixing with the list. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add negation (exclemation mark) to your your expression in loop in `getRandomIndex` method. Because now it looping until a random number is **IN** excludeList.

```
} while (!excludeList.contains(number));
```

In a moment when you are searching random integer, there is only one integer in `excludeList`, so it search some random int until it finds one that matches with integer excludeList. So you will get the same integer value every time.

Comment: I tried this method, doesn't work. When I press to enter the game it just turns black. The app doesn't respond at all.

Comment: So there is some other problem with your app.. There are error message?

Comment: this is all the information displayed in the monitor. No real error messages: https://ibb.co/dcnzVa <<--- only `boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView`

Comment: it is not an error, so there have to be error in your logic or layout ;)

Comment: Well, in that case I have no clue what and where to look.